# How do u call position x in a Combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a datagridview in C# that returns images from the database.

When executed it shows the pictures in a datagridview. At the same time the path is stored in a combobox.

Now my question is:

I have 9 pictures. On click of each picture it must open a new form and pass the path of that image to the next form.

How then do I pass, say path at position 6 in Combobox, without selecting the combobox items. Initially the combobox will be set to invisible.

Comment: How are you capturing the click? Pure Javascript, or a .NET event?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, mark it accordingly please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that is fired whenever someone clicks the datagrid, and do the following inside there:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            if (e.RowIndex == -1)
                 return;
            string path = comboBox1.Items[e.RowIndex].ToString();
            yourForm.Open(path);

}
```

Does this solve your problem, or did I understood it wrong?